# Replacing a string in url with another string

Tags: javascript, html

Replacing imgur with filmot,

Input box - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uguvn.jpg

Submit button

Once the submit is clicked in a new tab http://i.**filmot**.com/abcde.jpg has to open.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>input</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var res = str1.replace("imgur", "filmot");
    var win = window.open(res, '_blank');
    win.focus();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
 <input type=”text” id=”str1” />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The return code is not working. Please suggest.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Here is solution code :)

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>input</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById('str1').value;
  var res = str1.replace("imgur", "filmot");
  document.getElementById('str1').value = res;
  var win = window.open(res, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="str1" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var str1 = document.getElementById('str1').value; // add this
   var res = str1.replace("imgur", "filmot");
   var win = window.open(res, '_blank');
   win.focus();
} // <-----do a proper function closing.
</script>
```

Need to mention another thing may be the `type=”text” id=”str1”` quotes you are using, they are not the proper quotes. That should be changed to:

```
type="text" id="str1"
```

checkout the demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById('str1').value;
  var res = str1.replace("imgur", "filmot");
  document.getElementById('str1').value = res;
  //window.open(res, '_blank');
  //win.focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="str1" value="http://i.imgur.com/abcde.jpg" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

Comment: The snippet code works well! But the values I enter on input is dynamic so I pass an id with it to function.

Comment: @Vishnu that's fine! whatever url available in the text box your button will change the `imgur` to `filmot`.

Comment: After I click it changes to filmot for a second and changes back to imgur. I'm testing it as a html page.

Comment: @Vishnu Also check for your browser settings...Whether it's blocking popup ?

Comment: @Vishnu Its because of the form? Try adding a `type="button"` to the `button` or just remove the form tag.

Comment: @Vishnu yes form was getting submitted in your case and page gets refreshed and any changes with js resets to defaults of the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code.

```
var res = str1.replace("imgur", "filmot");
```

to

```
var res = $("#str1").val().replace("imgur", "filmot");
```

Your code wasn't getting the value from the textbox .. you were merely using a reference to the textbox.

**Update**

At the end of the function change `});` to `}`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I edited the code, but the new link is not opening in a new tab. Any idea where to edit?

Comment: @Vishnu remove the last parentheses and semi-colon `)` just after the brace `}`.

Comment: Did that and still not opening :/

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [**Opening a New Window**](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm) tutorial:

> To open a new window, you will need to use yet another ready-made JavaScript function. Here is what it looks like:

```
window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2')
```

And I've Edited the function (added the window name') and it's working fine, replaces the url a,nd open it in a new tab:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById('str1').value;
  var res = str1.replace("imgur", "filmot");
  window.open(res, 'new window', '_blank');
}
```

Here is [**the working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7y1f2c8m/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>input</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var newString=str1.value;
    var res = newString.replace("imgur", "filmot");
    var win = window.open(res, '_blank');
    win.focus();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
 <input type="text" id="str1" value=""/>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Click</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```